Interval obtained using Picard's existence and uniqueness theorem
For some constant $A$ consider $$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2,\quad y(0)=A$$
That being the problem statement, several answers were provided to choose the true statements from. This one was marked as a correct answer:
When $A=1$, the solution exists only on the interval $(-\infty,1)$.
The solution to the IVP is $y=\frac1{C-x}$ where $C=\frac1A$. When $A=1$, it is $y=\frac1{1-x}$. So it is not defined at $x=1$. But why is the interval $(1,\infty)$ not being considered?
Note: Some of the other statements were related to Picard's existence and uniqueness theorem. I can see that $0\in(-\infty, 1)$, but why it is considered as the only interval whereas $y=\frac1{1-x}$ is also defined on $(1,\infty)$?
(PS: This is a question from a test I faced)

How do you define a solution to an ODE with an initial condition?

@CheeHan sorry, I don't understand your question. Is it wrong to say y=1/(1-x) (or the solution) exists on (1, infinity)?

It's not wrong to say that the function $1/(1 - x)$ exists on the interval $(1, \infty)$, but this is different from saying that it is a solution to your initial value problem (IVP). So..... can you write down your definition of what it means for $y(x)$ to be a solution to an IVP?

I think it has to satisfy the differential equation and the given condition. So y=1/(1-x) satisfy y'=y^2 for all x in R{1} and also y(0)=1.

In the proof of Picard's existence and uniqueness theorem, the initial value problem
$$y'(x)=f(x,y), y(0)=y_0$$
is first reformulated as an equivalent integral equation,
$$y(x)=y_0+\int_0^xf(s,y(s))ds=:\Phi[y](x)$$
and then one proves that the fixed point equation $$y=\Phi[y]$$ has a unique solution in the space of continuous functions. Thus, a solution to the initial value problem is defined to be a continuous function (fulfilling the integral equation, which implies that it is also differentiable and fulfills the initial value) on an interval containing the point where the initial value is prescribed. That's why, in the above example, only the interval $(-\infty,1)$ is considered, as it is the largest interval which both contains the point where the initial value is prescribed and has the property that $y$ is continuous on the whole interval.
